# Can't export animations from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

I will try to be as thorough as possible by detailing every single step I made.

Here's a simple fidget popper object I made in blender:

[image: Fidget Popper]

There a lot of spheres as you can see in the image above. For it to be a fidget popper they have to pop down, so I needed to create a pop down animation. To do that I added a Shrinkwrap modifier to each and every sphere and then I selected "Apply as Shape Key" on these modifiers. You can see the resulting Shape Keys on the right in the image below:

[image]

And finally I created an animation using these shape keys. The animation starts at the shape key value of 0.000 and ends at the value 1.000 as you can see from this short clip:

[Pop Down Animation video](https://streamable.com/7dcnhy)

This animation was done to each sphere.

So far so good. Now I want to export everything to Unity, and that's where I've been stuck for days. If I drag the .blender file into Unity then the animations for all the spheres get joined into one single animation, which is bad because I need each sphere to animate individually. I then tried exporting an FBX file with the default FBX settings and not a single animation got imported into Unity. What's the correct way to import all the animations into Unity? Thanks for reaching the end :)

Comment: Anybody?...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export as FBX and in Unity you can make a script or animation to control your shape keys. In Unity shape keys are called BlendShapes.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BlendShapes.html